# how to fix this Unsafe use of a nullable receiver of type Array?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file

It's a whatsapp story saver app. Till Android 9 it's fine, but when I tried to use it on Android 10 it's crashing with the below stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: files must not be null
    at com.shaikjaleel.wsave.fragments.VideosFragment$loadStories$1$1.invoke(VideosFragment.kt:84)
    at com.shaikjaleel.wsave.fragments.VideosFragment$loadStories$1$1.invoke(VideosFragment.kt:30)
    at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$uiThread$1.run(Async.kt:70)

also android studio throws this warning ( Unsafe use of a nullable receiver of type Array<File!>?
```

[VideoFragment.kt](https://github.com/iamsj7/WSave-Stories/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/shaikjaleel/wsave/fragments/VideosFragment.kt)

```
    private fun loadStories() {
        if (!storagePermissionGranted()) {
            toast(getString(R.string.message_permissions_required))
            stopRefreshing()
            return
        }

        val dir = File(K.WHATSAPP_STORIES)
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs()

        doAsync {
            val files = dir.listFiles { _, s ->
                s.endsWith(".mp4") || s.endsWith(".gif") }

            uiThread {

                if (files.isNotEmpty()) {
                    hasStories()

                    for (file in files.sortedBy { it.lastModified() }.reversed()) {
                        val story = Story(K.TYPE_VIDEO, file.absolutePath)
                        adapter.addStory(story)
                    }

                } else {
                    noStories()
                }

                stopRefreshing()
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change if (files.isNotEmpty()) { to if (files?.isEmpty() != false) {

Comment: `files?.isEmpty() != false` is true if `files` is `null`, so will throw at `files.sortedBy...`.

Comment: @Alexey my bad, should be ?.isNotEmpty() == true

Comment: after using this `if (files?.isNotEmpty() == true) {`
2020-08-07 15:11:02.865 28678-28811/com.shaikjaleel.wsave E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.shaikjaleel.wsave
2020-08-07 15:11:02.865 28678-28811/com.shaikjaleel.wsave E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Now app is opening fine but it not syncing the files in the directory

Answer (score 1):

[STORAGE ACCESS PERMISSION SAF (MEDIUM)](https://medium.com/@sriramaripirala/android-10-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-da8b630a89df)

```
if (files?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
```

added this in code and added permission `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`  in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this

> Unsafe use of a nullable receiver of type Array<File!>?

is just a warning instead of an error. I also assume line 84 in the error message is

```
if (files.isNotEmpty()) {
```

If so, I'd rewrite it as

```
if (files != null && files.isNotEmpty())
```

Or

```
if (files?.isNotEmpty() ?: false)
```

but I think the first one is cleaner.

Comment: Yes i know it's just a warning. But when coming to making this app compatible with API 29 android 10 app crashes with the above error log. It's all fine till android 9 API 28. if i do the below changes app isn't crashing it's getting installed but later it not showing the directory files. ( It always remains null ) means no files

Comment: `if (files?.isNotEmpty() ?: false)` added this and read logs thoroughly it was the issue with Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
so i added this permission in `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ` in Manifest the issue is fixed now

Thanks everyone